# How do I make a form field go back invisble after I uncheck a radio button?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I'm currently building a form where the goal is that the administrator will have to choose between 3 radio buttons. If one click on any of the radios, a specific field shows up (There are 3 fields set as "invisible"). My issue is that, I have no problem making these fields show up, but they don't disappear if I select something else.

Here is my code:

```
function walk_handler_form_alter (&$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  $form['field_prestation_walk']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name="field_prestation_type"][value="walk"]' => [
        'checked' => true
      ]
    ]
  ];
}
```

So, as I said earlier, this code makes my forms show when I click on their related radios. However, if I click on another radio, they don't disappear.

I had a lot of troubles to find some documentation about that (well, I found some, but the examples given wheren't thorough enough for me). Also, I tried to add an `invisible` after the `visible` one, with the exact condition except that 'checked' was set to false, but it didn't work.

Should I use plain Javascript / jQuery for this, or am I just it the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello try this ...

```
$form['field_prestation_walk']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':input[name="field_prestation_type"]' => [
        'value' => 'walk'
      ],
    ]
  ];
```

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than expected!